# Color Code Cells of xtable

Tags: r, latex, sweave, xtable

I've used R, sweave (but **not** knitr, and xtable, to create a table, where 1 column is an identifier, and the other three columns are "flag" columns that are either blank or contain a 1 (the flag).

I want to be able to shad the last three columns so each cell is either green (if it is blank) or red (if it contains a 1).

```
<<xtable3, results=tex>>=
id <- c("1_1", "1_2", "2_1")
a <- c(1,"","")
b <- c("", 1, "")
c <- c("", "", 1)
d <- data.frame(id, a,b,c)
dx <- xtable(d)
align(dx) <- "|c|c|c|c|c|"
print(dx, hline.after=-1:3)
@
```

*Edit:* This is the output I get via Sumatra PDF Viewer:

[image]

I have made several attempts, unfortunately I didn't save them before posting this question and I cannot recall any of the attempts exactly.

Even if someone could just point me in the right directions I would really appreciate it. I've been able to find information on R and LaTeX, but not information that is for R/Sweave **and** Latex.

Comment: You need to specify an output device. If you are asking about using the console device, then you will need something smarter than the usual console.

Comment: See the edit above

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there's a clever way to do this with `xtable`, but I'm notoriously bad at getting `xtable` to do what I want.  Here's an approach using `pixiedust` that may give you what you need.  (The tricky part here is identifying the coordinates of the table that you want to shade).

EDIT: I apologize, my original answer didn't satisfy all the requirements you laid out.  This has the proper colors with red in the cells with a 1, and green otherwise.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "May 25, 2016"
output: pdf_document
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{amssymb} 
  - \usepackage{arydshln} 
  - \usepackage{caption} 
  - \usepackage{graphicx} 
  - \usepackage{hhline} 
  - \usepackage{longtable} 
  - \usepackage{multirow} 
  - \usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor} 
  - \makeatletter 
  - \newcommand*\vdashline{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\$\dabar@\dabar@\dabar@\$}} 
  - \makeatother
---

```{r}
library(pixiedust)
id <- c("1_1", "1_2", "2_1")
a <- c(1,"","")
b <- c("", 1, "")
c <- c("", "", 1)
d <- data.frame(id, a,b,c)

cols <- apply(d[, -1], 1, function(x) which(x == 1)) + 1
rows <- apply(d[, -1], 2, function(x) which(x == 1))

dust(d,
 float = FALSE,
 hhline = TRUE) %>%
  medley_all_borders() %>%
  sprinkle(cols = 2:4,
           bg = "green") %>%
  sprinkle(rows = rows,
           cols = cols,
           fixed = TRUE,
           bg = "red")

```
````

### Sweave Adaptation

The same code can be used in Sweave, but requires a couple of adaptations.  The equivalent code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{arydshln} 
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{hhline} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor} 
\makeatletter 
\newcommand*\vdashline{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\$\dabar@\dabar@\dabar@\$}} 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<chunk1, results = tex>>=
library(pixiedust)
options(pixiedust_print_method = "latex")

id <- c("1_1", "1_2", "2_1")
a <- c(1,"","")
b <- c("", 1, "")
c <- c("", "", 1)
d <- data.frame(id, a,b,c)

cols <- apply(d[, -1], 1, function(x) which(x == 1)) + 1
rows <- apply(d[, -1], 2, function(x) which(x == 1))

dust(d,
 float = FALSE,
 hhline = TRUE) %>%
  medley_all_borders() %>%
  sprinkle(cols = 1,
           sanitize = TRUE) %>%
  sprinkle(cols = 2:4,
           bg = "green") %>%
  sprinkle(rows = rows,
           cols = cols,
           fixed = TRUE,
           bg = "red") %>%
  print(asis = FALSE) %>%
  cat()

@


\end{document}
```

Comment: Does this use knitr or just sweave? I am only using sweave.

Comment: My apologies, I missed that salient detail.  I've added a section appropriate for use in Sweave.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

<<results='asis'>>=
library('xtable')
library('dplyr')

id <- c("1\\_1", "1\\_2", "2\\_1")
a <- c(1,"","")
b <- c("", 1, "")
c <- c("", "", 1)
d <- data.frame(id, a,b,c)

d %>% mutate_each(funs(paste0(ifelse(.=='', '\\cellcolor{red!25} ','\\cellcolor{green!25} '),.)), a:c) -> d

dx <- xtable(d)
align(dx) <- "|c|c|c|c|c|"
print(dx, hline.after=-1:3,
      sanitize.text.function=identity)
@


\end{document}
```

Comment: When I tried running this code I got the following message:  `Writing to file latex_practice_1.tex
Processing code chunks with options ...
Error in match.arg(options$results, c("verbatim", "tex", "hide")) : 
  'arg' should be one of "verbatim", "tex", "hide"
Calls: <Anonymous> -> SweaveParseOptions -> check -> match.arg
Execution halted`

Comment: This is a `knitr` document, not a `Sweave` doc. I'm assuming changing `'asis'` to `'tex'` might do it if you're set on Sweave.

Comment: I tried running it after changing it to `"verbatim"`, `"tex"`, `"hide"`, `verbatim`, `tex`, and `hide`. and it kept giving me the same error.

Comment: I've tried changing that and it still doesn't work. Is there something else I would need to change to make it a `Sweave` doc and not a `knitr` doc?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a Sweave file that will conditionally color xtable cells red or green. The conditional formatting of each cell is accomplished with the LaTeX colortbl and xcolor packages.

Coloring xtable cells with Sweave involves pasting together an escape character ("\"), the LaTeX "\cellcolor" function, an HTML argument, your color choice, and your cell value. You'll want to have columns that look something like this before you convert the data.frame to xtable:

```
c("\\cellcolor[HTML]{FF0600}{1}", 
"\\cellcolor[HTML]{2DB200}{}", 
"\\cellcolor[HTML]{2DB200}{}")
```

Here is the full Sweave file. I am compiling this in RStudio using knitr and pdfLaTeX, and I'm previewing it in Sumatra.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

<<xtable1, results = 'asis', echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE>>=
library(xtable)

# build your data.frame
id <- c("1_1", "1_2", "2_1")
a <- c("1", "", "")
b <- c("", "1", "")
c <- c("", "", "1")
d <- data.frame(id, a, b, c)

# define function that will color blank cells green and not blank cells red
color_cells <- function(df, var){
  out <- ifelse(df[, var]=="", 
                      paste0("\\cellcolor[HTML]{2DB200}{", df[, var], "}"),
                      paste0("\\cellcolor[HTML]{FF0600}{", df[, var], "}"))
}

# apply coloring function to each column you want
d$a <- color_cells(df = d, var= "a")
d$b <- color_cells(df = d, var= "b")
d$c <- color_cells(df = d, var= "c")

# convert data.frame to xtable and print it with sanitization
dx <- xtable(d)
align(dx) <- "|c|c|c|c|c|"
print(dx, 
      hline.after=-1:3,
      sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
@

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Edit

Here is the code for compiling with Sweave, not knitr:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}

<<xtable1, results = tex, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE>>=
library(xtable)

# build your data.frame
id <- c("1_1", "1_2", "2_1")
a <- c("1", "", "")
b <- c("", "1", "")
c <- c("", "", "1")
d <- data.frame(id, a, b, c)

# define function that will color NA cells green and not-NA cells red
color_cells <- function(df, var){
  out <- ifelse(df[, var]=="", 
                      paste0("\\cellcolor[HTML]{2DB200}{", df[, var], "}"),
                      paste0("\\cellcolor[HTML]{FF0600}{", df[, var], "}"))
}

# apply coloring function to each column you want
d$a <- color_cells(df = d, var= "a")
d$b <- color_cells(df = d, var= "b")
d$c <- color_cells(df = d, var= "c")

# convert data.frame to xtable and print it with sanitization
dx <- xtable(d)
align(dx) <- "|c|c|c|c|c|"
print(dx, 
      hline.after=-1:3,
      sanitize.text.function = function(x) x)
@

\end{document}
```

Comment: When I tried running this code I got the following message:  `Writing to file latex_practice_1.tex
Processing code chunks with options ...
Error in match.arg(options$results, c("verbatim", "tex", "hide")) : 
  'arg' should be one of "verbatim", "tex", "hide"
Calls: <Anonymous> -> SweaveParseOptions -> check -> match.arg
Execution halted`

Comment: Since you're compiling with Sweave and not knitr, try changing the start of the code chunk to this: <<xtable1, results = tex, echo = FALSE, warning = FALSE>>=

Comment: You'll also need to add \SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE} after \begin{document}

Comment: What does this piece of of code do: `sanitize.text.function = function(x) x`

Comment: I have used the code above and it is making the background of the red cells, but it is not inputting the green background.

Comment: This code only made the the cells red. It didn't add the green background. What do I do to add the green background?

Comment: `sanitize.text.function = function(x) x` passes the character vectors in your xtable object into the print.xtable sanitize.text.function, which removes characters with special meaning in LaTeX. For our purposes here, it properly formats the backslashes for LaTeX. The function is used in the [xtable Gallery](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf) on page 13..

Comment: The Sweave code here compiled a .pdf containing the table above, which I screenshot to grab that image. It works fine for me. Have you made any alterations to this code? If you made alterations, I will need to see them to be of more help.